# Left-Align Custom Checkbox and Center Text Inside Div (Input + Div)

Tags: css, checkbox

Thanks in advance for your help.

So I have custom checkbox inputs. When you click the label or the input the div's border and the label text change colors, and the check appears.

The only issue is, I need the check to align left, while the text remains centered, regardless of the checkbox status (currently when the checkbox is checked, the label jumps over to the right). Any idea how to get the checkbox to the left and keep the text centered, and stationary?

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
div.label {
border:solid 1px gray;
line-height:40px;
height:40px;
width: 250px;
border-radius:40px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
margin-top:10px;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
color:gray;
text-align:center;
}

label {
display:inline;
text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

input:checked + div {
border: solid 1px red;
color: #F00;
}

input:checked + div:before {
content: "\2713";
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="lists[Travel]" type="checkbox" name="lists[Travel]" />
<div class="label">
<label for="lists[Travel]">Travel</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add absolute position to input:checked + div:before ... like this :

```
input:checked + div:before {
content: "\2713";
position: absolute;
margin-left: -50px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a class on the input:checked + div:before?       Basically I have 2 columns of inputs and the checkboxes are appearing at the same place for both columns.

Comment: I ended up changing the divs in the right column to spans, and defined the span and input states as well. Works fine, but if there's a better way, I'd love to learn!